# Caching list of id's of django queryset, and reusing that list for another Viewset

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-queryset

Let's use these 4 simple models for example. A city can have multiple shops, and a shop can have multiple products, and a product can have multiple images.

**models.py**

```
class City(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=300)

class Shop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City, related_name='related_city', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Product(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=300)
    description=models.CharField(max_length=5000)
    shop=models.ForeignKey(Shop, related_name='related_shop', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Image(models.Model):
    image=models.ImageField(null=True)
    product=models.ForeignKey(Product, related_name='related_product', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

For an eCommerce website, users will be writing keywords and I filter on the products names, to get the matching results. I also want to fetch together the related data of shops, cities and images, relevant to the products I will be showing.
To achieve that I am using .select_related() to retrieve the other objects from the foreignKeys as well.

Now, my question is, what is the best way to send that to the client?

One way is to make a single serializer, that groups all data from all 4 tables in a single JSON. That JSON will look like 1NF, since it will have many repetitions, for example, there will be new row for every image, and every shop that the product can be found, and the 10.000 character long description will be repeated for each row, so this is not such a good idea. More specifically the fields are: (product_id, product_name, product_description, product_image_filepath, product_in_shop_id, shop_in_city_id)

The second approach will use Django queryset caching, which I have no experience at all, and maybe you can give me advice on how to make it efficient.

The second way would be to get Product.objects.filter(by input keywords).select_related().all(), cache this list of id's of products, and return this queryset of the viewset.
Then, from the client's side, I make another GET request, just for the images, and I don't know how to reuse the list of id's of products, that I queried earlier, in the previous viewset / queryset.

How do I fetch only the images that I need, for products that matched the user input keywords, such that I don't need to query the id's of products again?
How will the code look like exactly, for caching this in one viewset, and reusing it again in another viewset?

Then I also need one more GET request to get the list of shops and cities, where the product is available, so it will be fantastic if I can reuse the list of id's I got from the first queryset to fetch the products.

Is the second approach a good idea? If yes, how to implement it exactly?

Or should I stick with the first approach, which I am sceptical is the right way to do this.

I am using PostgreSQL database, and I will probably end up using ElasticSearch for my search engine, to quickly find the matching keywords.